# ADD or SUB with only two operands in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am learning ARM Assembly Language. 
I'v read ADD should have 3 operands. However, I'v seen many cases in reality there are only two. such as:

```
STR     R1, [SP,#0x20+var_1C]
LDR     R1, =(a_lua - 0x1DE4E6)
MOVS    R0, R4          ; haystack
ADD     R1, PC          
BLX     strstr
CMP     R0, #0
BNE     loc_1DE4FA
```

Can any one help me with the meaning of ADD with two operands? Many thanks!

Comment: With 3 operands you can specify a destination that's different from either of the two operands if you want to (`A = B + C`). With two operands you can't (you get `A = A + B`).

Comment: its thumb mode instructions

Comment: Where did you read "it should have 3 operands"?

Comment: The code is from Android file with "go" extension. And I just read a few chapter of the book ARM Assembly Language and all ADD is with three operands. I think it will be the same as ADD r1, r1, pc.

Comment: Android native build system defaults to Thumb, and on most modern CPUs, it's the right call. See if there's `CODE16` or `THUMB` directive near the top of the file.

Comment: It's a CODE32 near top of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the information in the comments that this really is ARM code, not 16-bit Thumb, then the answer is that your reference material predates UAL.

The introduction of the Thumb-2 instruction set brought along a [modified assembly syntax](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0379d/Cjagjjbc.html) called *Unified Assembly Language* which superceded the previous syntaxes for ARM and Thumb. Rather than have two separate (and incompatible) languages, UAL allows (within reason) the same source to be assembled to either ARM or Thumb instructions. One of the consequences of this is that for any 3-operand ARM instructions that has a 2-operand Thumb equivalent, specifying the destination register is optional - if omitted it will default to the first source register*.

Most assemblers will still support the older pre-UAL syntax for compatibility, but it's worth updating to a more modern reference once you get past the basics since there are some potentially confusing changes (like nearly all of the floating-point mnemonics).

<sub>* except in the case of `MUL` where it's the other way round for awkward technical reasons.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

This is a shortcut notation, there is no 2 operand add or sub in ARM (however Thumb does have them).

```
add r0, r1
```

basically means use the first operand as the destination and first source register.  It is identical to the instruction below and gets assembled to the same instruction.

```
add r0, r0, r1
```